# mysql freeradius

Tags: mysql, radius

I just installed `freeradius-server-2.2.0` from tarball.

I want to connect freeradius using mysql server.

But when i running radius on foreground with `radiusd -X` and I got error message like bellow :

```
Fri Mar  8 13:44:46 2013 : Debug:   group_membership_query = "SELECT groupname           FROM radusergroup           WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}'           ORDER BY priority"
Fri Mar  8 13:44:46 2013 : Debug:   connect_failure_retry_delay = 60
Fri Mar  8 13:44:46 2013 : Debug:   simul_count_query = ""
Fri Mar  8 13:44:46 2013 : Debug:   simul_verify_query = "SELECT radacctid, acctsessionid, username,                                nasipaddress, nasportid, framedipaddress,                                callingstationid, framedprotocol                                FROM radacct                                WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}'                                AND acctstoptime IS NULL"
Fri Mar  8 13:44:46 2013 : Debug:   postauth_query = "INSERT INTO radpostauth                           (username, pass, reply, authdate)                           VALUES (                           '%{User-Name}',                           '%{%{User-Password}:-%{Chap-Password}}',                           '%{reply:Packet-Type}', '%S')"
Fri Mar  8 13:44:46 2013 : Debug:   safe-characters = "@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-_: /"
Fri Mar  8 13:44:46 2013 : Debug:   }
Fri Mar  8 13:44:46 2013 : Error: Could not link driver rlm_sql_mysql: rlm_sql_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Fri Mar  8 13:44:46 2013 : Error: Make sure it (and all its dependent libraries!) are in the search path of your system's ld.
Fri Mar  8 13:44:46 2013 : Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/sql.conf[22]: Instantiation failed for module "sql"
Fri Mar  8 13:44:46 2013 : Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[177]: Failed to find "sql" in the "modules" section.
Fri Mar  8 13:44:46 2013 : Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[69]: Errors parsing authorize section.
```

It's also happen on my freeradius ldap?

```
[error LDAP]
/usr/local/etc/raddb/modules/ldap[29]: Failed to link to module 'rlm_ldap': rlm_ldap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 
/usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[305]: Failed to find "ldap" in the "modules" section.
/usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[305]: Failed to parse "ldap"
```

How i can solve this issue ?

i've installed `libmysqlclient-dev` on my ubuntu.

I'm running on `Ubuntu 12.04`.

Help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You did re-run configure right, after installing the development headers?

When building from source you will need to do a:

```
./configure <options> && make && make install
```

To actually install the module.